# Ubuntu openssl not asking for Common Name

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, ubuntu-12.04, csr

I have Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS and OpenSSL 1.0.1 versions installed. I want to generate a CSR for SSL and when I run,

```
openssl genrsa -out domain.key 2048
```

I get following output,

```
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
..+++
.......................+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
```

and it doesn't ask for Common Name or anything and generates a key. What's causing this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you issued is doing exactly what you have asked, it is to say to generate  a 2048 private key.

Now you need to generate a CSR (a request certificate) where you will have to provide the required information including of course the CN.

Try adding

```
openssl req -new -key <MyPrivate.key> -out <MyRequest.csr>
```

where you need to replace `<MyPrivate.key>` with the filename of your private key generated in the previous step and `<MyRequest.csr>` is the filename of the certificate request. This csr must be sent to the certificate authority for validation and signature.

I hope it helps

cheers

Comment: Yes your answer is right, thanks very much for prompt reply.